# Kill tmux session after script is done

Tags: bash, shell-script, tmux

I have a `bash` script that I use to run a script inside a `tmux` session. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
session="myjob"
tmux new-session -d -s $session
tmux send-keys 'myscript' 'C-m'
```

The problem is that after `myscript` is done, the session `myjob` remains. I want to automatically kill it after `myscript` is finished. I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
session="myjob"
tmux new-session -d -s $session
tmux send-keys 'myscript' 'C-m'
tmux kill-session -t $session
```

but this skips `myscript` entirely and goes straight to killing the session.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why start a tmux session to run an automated script? Why not just execute the script in the normal shell? Thanks for helping me understand the context.

Comment: This is running in a computational cluster and I want to be able to log out, that's why I use `tmux`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
tmux send-keys 'exec myscript' 'C-m'
```

With that, the shell will `exec` the script (i.e, `myscript` will replace the shell process instead of getting started as a child).  Then, when that process terminates, it'll be the process that `tmux` ran, so `tmux` will clean up after it.